# install gitlab on local server (intranet)

Tags: gitlab, intranet, localserver

I've installed ubuntu server with gui on my local server, then installed gitlab. My question is, what should I place in the EXTERNAL URL field? I don't have a domain name. Should I set a static IP and point it there?

Comment: This might be better suited to https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

yes.. just use your static ip address, but use `http` instead of `https` 
 *e.g* :

```
external_url 'http://192.168.99.99'
```